# There are no usable controls in this group. Drag an item onto this text to add it to the toolbox

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, ssis-2019

I faced this situation once, it's not a visual studio issue.

This message I have seen in "Toolbox", but while we working in SSIS we need "SSIS Toolbox"

To open SSIS toolbox

1. We can open any of the dtsx file and click on SSIS Toolbox button which we can see on top right, refer the image below.

[image]

2. We can right click on blank area of dtsx file and click on SSIS Toolbox option from the list as we can see below.

[image]

Hope it works for all of us.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question. You will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It helped me, this ticket gets my vote as I was too dumb to realise SSIS Toolbox is different to the "Toolbox"! I just got a new laptop and I had to install VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

If you already under the Design mode, you can right click at the Toolbox field and select `Show All`, `Reset Toolbox` or `Choose Item` and add the controls or reset them back like the following:

[image]